# HTML edits not showing

Tags: html, http, https, server, browser-cache

I’m working on a simple webpage with just an index.html file. If I make changes to the html file and then upload the file to my server, when I reload the page using the url with only http the changes I made show, for example, if I remove the index.html file and reload the page it says could not load page, not found. If I do the same thing but use https, the page still loads even if the index.html file is deleted from the server. I have deleted and cleared cache and website data from my iPhone. This seems to happen on iOS in both safari and Firefox on my iPhone but not on a computer. Does the https cache differently or store files in a different directory?

Comment: https shouldn't work differently. This likely has to do with your specific host.

Comment: I have not ran in to this on other sites on the same host. Do you have any suggestions as to what I can check to see?  It almost seems as if it is a different directory

Comment: No, because this is going to be wildly dependent on your host, the software they use and how it's configured. It's also possible they use a caching proxy/cdn.